# How to add a file (text or image) to iphone app through itunes?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to add a file (image or text) to already install app in the iphone through itunes (or any other way)?

I'm working on an app, in which I want to add a feature for adding external file (like text or image file).

Please help me, how can I achieve this?

Or it is not possible in current SDK?

Note : I don't want to do this through downloading from internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding but if the app is already on the App Store you could just rebuild it with the file and update the binary.

Otherwise it is possible to register a custom URL scheme and pass data through a URL (encode in base 64 for more bang for your buck). There is a game called Moonlight Mahjong that does this to download new mahjong layouts that are then saved onto the device.